# How to set unique constraint on two foreign fields in Grails?

Tags: grails

Suppose I have a class with following definition:

```
class ClassA { 
    static belongsTo = [ownerB:ClassB, ownerC:ClassC]
}
```

How I can enforce an unique constraint on above "belongsTo" relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Map form of `belongsTo` creates fields with those names, so you can do it with

```
static constraints = {
   ownerB unique: 'ownerC'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Creating-a-foreign-key-constraint-td1352053.html

Comment: I cant see anything related to unique constraints from yout link, sorry

Comment: only a link posting and add to that the question is unrelated to the question answered in the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
String field1
String field2
Integer field3
SomeObject object

  static constraints = {
        object unique: ['field1','field2', 'field3']
    }
```